# What notation can be used for file sizes in PHP's ini files?

Tags: php, ini

As an example, by default, the `memory_limit` directive will have a value like `128M`. What other units can be used?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `K` (for Kilobytes), `M` (for Megabytes) and `G` (for Gigabytes). They are *case insensitive* so you can alternatively use `k`, `m`, or `g` respectively.

Source: [PHP.net FAQs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes)

Comment: The php.net page you linked notes: “The PHP notation describes one kilobyte as equalling 1024 bytes, whereas the IEC standard considers this to be a kibibyte instead. Summary: k and K = 1024 bytes.”. So, according to PHP notation, `2K = 2 * 1024 = 2048 bytes`, `2M = 2 * 1024 * 1024 = 2,097,152 bytes`, and `2GB = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 2,147,483,648 bytes`. This conflicts with SI notation in which the prefix K indicates one thousand units, M one million, and G one billion.